# Google spreadsheet urlfetch error and updating formula error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have Google spreadsheet formula as below

```
function mydata(para1, para2, para3){
  var myurl = "http://someurl/data2?one="+ para1 +"&two=" + para2 + "&three="+para3;
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myurl);

  var result1 = Utilities.jsonParse(result.getContentText());
  if (result1.length === 0){
      return null;
    }else{
      return result1;
    }

}
```

i have used this formula 400+ times in my spreadsheet. Issue is many of those cells in which this formula is present are showing error as `Error: Service invoked too many times in a short time: urlfetch. Try Utilities.sleep(1000)`
This is the 1st issue.
and if i edit that formula cell and click again.. then the error is still present. It should reload/re-compute that formula. This is my 2nd issue.

**Many stackoverflow solutions and various blog post have suggested try using `Utilities.sleep(1000)`; but here how can i use it?? i am not running any loop in which on each loop i should wait like this.** So how to control this behavior here.
Also in 2nd issue; i think that google spreadsheet is caching the result; but i didn't get how to modify/alter that "onEdit"

Comment: What "result" do you think Google is caching? Please edit your original post and provide an example of this.

Comment: result is json array of numbers and strings; example: `[["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]["23.2", "10.5", "15.6", "12.9"]]`

Comment: if i change the parameters; then only it will update the formula; and after doing this; when i define the original parameters(reverting my changes); it doesn't update the cell immediately... but after some time/some more such trials it is updating....but not immediately!!!!

Comment: Can you give an real url for us to see?

Answer (score 0):

> Many stackoverflow solutions and various blog post have suggested try using Utilities.sleep(1000); but here how can i use it?

After the URL fetch request would be fine. Even though you are not running any loops, the function must be getting called a lot in order for Google to return that error. If you're calling the function in onEdit, then that would cause the function to get called a lot. Share more of your code if you need help figuring out why the function is getting called a lot.

```
function mydata(para1, para2, para3){
  var myurl = "http://someurl/data2?one="+ para1 +"&two=" + para2 + "&three="+para3;
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myurl);
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  var result1 = Utilities.jsonParse(result.getContentText());
  if (result1.length === 0) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return result1;
    }
}
```

Comment: my code is just that... i can't share the original URL on which i am making requests;i have to get the permission; if i get that..  i will update that in question; but the whole function is same!

Comment: also i have already tried you answer in past; still the problem is there and code become very slow.